# Ionic 2: similar $ionicSlideBoxDelegate service?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

Is there something similar to ionicSlideBoxDelegate service in Ionic 2 or some way to reference the ion-slides presented in the view?

Answer (score 1):

With the Latest Version of Ionic 2. You have to do something like below.
In Markup, create a local variable on ***ion-slides*** element.

```
<ion-slides #mySlider></ion-slides>
```

Here **#mySlider** is a local Variable.

In Controller, get the reference of ion-slider using local variable and @ViewChild Decorator, Like below.

```
@ViewChild('mySlider') slider: Slides;
```

This is equivalent to $ionicSlideBoxDelegate Service. Now you can excess slider's API like below.

```
this.slider.slideTo(2, 500);
```

This will make slider to go to slide at index 2 with 500ms speed.
I hope this answers your question.

Comment: thank you. not sure why it is not accepted s an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab your slide component by using its Id.

```
  constructor(
    private _app: IonicApp
  ){}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.slider = this._app.getComponent('my-slider');
  }
```